# Cannot collect streamlit form data

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to built a streamlit catbot, where there is a feedback form. I want the chatbot to work in the following way: For any user inputthe chabot returns "abc" (say). After each response the chatbot shares a feedback form to ask user whether the user is satisfied or not. If user selects "yes" option, the chatbot does noting and the chat continues. If the user selects "no" option =, the chatbot returns "xyz" (say).

Now, I am unable to capture what feedback the user gives. Whenever I hit the submit button in the feedback form, nothing happens only the chat history remains printed.

Following is the code that I am using. Kindly help me figure out the issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(page_title="chatbot")
st.title("chatbot")

if chat_history not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.chat_history = []

for message in st.session_state.chat_history:
    with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
        st.markdown(message["text"])

input_text = st.chat_input("chat here")

if input_text:
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(input_text)

    st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role":"user", "text":input_text})
    
    chat_response = "abc"
    
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        st.markdown(chat_response)

    st.session_state.chat_history.append({"role":"assistant", "text":chat_response})
    
    if "feedback" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.feedback = []
    
    with st.form("FeedbackForm"):
        option = st.radio("Give your feedback here: ", ["yes", "no"], index = None)
        if st.form_submit_button("submit"):
            st.session_state.feedback.append([option])
            st.markdown("you selected", option):
            if option=="no":
                with st.chat_message("assistant"):
                    st.markdown("xyz")
```